# Bootstrap Vue modal

Tags: vuejs2, bootstrap-modal, bootstrap-vue

I am using bootstrap-vue modals in my small project and I can not figure out why my modal's layout is soo off.

[Here is the screen](https://i.stack.imgur.com/fdEb8.png)

As you can see, it is not even possible to click on the input field.

Here is my code, nothing special:

```
<b-modal
      id="insert-name"
      title="Name"
    >
      <form ref="form">
        <b-form-group
          label="Name"
          label-for="name-input"
        >
          <b-form-input
            id="name-input"
            v-model="name"
          ></b-form-input>
        </b-form-group>
      </form>
    </b-modal>
```

I am using vue "2.6.12" and bootstrap-vue "2.21.2".

Comment: Change `<form>` to `<b-form>`.  Otherwise, the code looks ok.  Maybe there's an issue with the surrounding template.

Comment: I actually figured out why this happened. It's after I installed sass-loader. But still don't know how to fix it.